# Visual Basic optional argument

Tags: vbscript

I trying to set optional argument

`Public Property Get val(Optional text)`

But i get error

```
Microsoft VBScript compilation error '800a03f2'

Expected identifier

/classes\X-Session.asp, line 13

Public Property Get val(Optional text)
------------------------^
```

How to write right syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VBScript does not support optional parameters. [Evidence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/30593abb%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) (search for "Optional")